# Cannot read properties of null "querySelector" but the property is defined?

Tags: javascript

I am following a video to make a Jeopardy type game. once I get down to the elements it throws an error : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector').

I'm not sure where my mistake is . My board is defined in my html, I see no spelling errors yet still the error.
This is the HTML portion below.

```
  <body>
   <div class="app">
    <header class="top-header">
        <h1>Trivia Game Show</h1>
        <p class="score">Score <span class="score-count"></span></p>
    </header>

    <!--container for the board-->
  <div class="board"></div> 
    <!--categories get injected here-->
```

then in my JS I have this

```
//elements
   this.boardElement = element.querySelector(".board");
   this.scoreCountElement = element.querySelector(".score-count");
   this.formElement = element.querySelector("form");
   this.inputElement = element.querySelector("input[name=user-answer]");
   this.modalElement = element.querySelector(".card-modal");
   this.clueTextElement = element.querySelector(".clue-text");
   this.resultElement = element.querySelector(".result");
   this.resultTextElement = element.querySelector(".result_correct-answer-text");
   this.successTextElement = element.querySelector(".result_success");
   this.failTextElement = element.querySelector(".result_fail");
```

I'm confused on where my error is. I have my .board defined in my Html yet it tells me its Null?
how do I fix this error ? TIA !!

This is where it was declared

```
class TriviaGameshow{
constructor(element, options={}) {


   this.useCategoryIds = options.useCategoryIds || [1892, 4483, 88, 218];

   this.categories = [];
   this.clues = {};


   this.currentClue = null;
   this.score = 0;


   this.currentClue = null;
   this.score = 0;




   this.boardElement = document.querySelector(".board");
   this.scoreCountElement = element.querySelector(".score-count");
   this.formElement = element.querySelector("form");
   this.inputElement = element.querySelector("input[name=user-answer]");
   this.modalElement = element.querySelector(".card-modal");
   this.clueTextElement = element.querySelector(".clue-text");
   this.resultElement = element.querySelector(".result");
   this.resultTextElement = element.querySelector(".result_correct-answer-text");
   this.successTextElement = element.querySelector(".result_success");
   this.failTextElement = element.querySelector(".result_fail");



}
```

}

Comment: In your provided code, what's `element`?  That's the variable that is `null`.  As a starter, try changing that to `document`, eg `document.querySelector(".board")`

Comment: Well I'm rather new to this and while I do know normally document.query would normally go there , Im following a tutorial and from what I can understand, this is to  reference the elements without the dom query  every time?  The video is using an API .

Comment: Here is the link to the video on youtube, the information is at time marker 7:47.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYMBkayHmUo&t=467s      THANKS for any insight !! much appriciated

Comment: In the video, 7:40, `element` is defined on line 16: `constructor(element...`  - so it's possible you're missing that or have a typo on that line.   Can you include a bit more of your code?  Or, possibly, you've put your element.query... code outside the closing `}` (line 36 @7:40) - it needs to be inside that bracket.

Comment: Here is a Link to the code in codepen. https://codepen.io/NP27/details/qBPydLw

Comment: We need to see how `element` is defined in your code. In the example you linked the element is `<div class="app"><div>`. It's passed at the end with this line of code:

`const game = new TriviaGameShow( document.querySelector(".app"), {});`

The error you have is weird, because it means element is actually set to `null`. If it was not defined the error would be `Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined`

Comment: @svrbst Not weird, `querySelector` returns `null` when it doesn't find the element by the selector.

Comment: ive included more code in my edit..  I

Comment: Based on your codepen, you're including the script in `<head>`, so the DOM isn't fully parsed, hence `null` in the query selector. Move the script to end of body, add `defer` etc

Comment: Phix.  that was it .... what a mess for a silly mistake!  Your awesome TY !

Answer (score 1):

check the class. or redeclare the class

1. this.boardElement = document.querySelector(".board");
   if doing this error not resolve simply copy the class '.board' and then paste it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).